# Check for new versions of lists on server, download it and update combo boxes

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, combobox, webclient, auto-update

I'm creating C# app that can download tools from different sources. There are six combo boxes for every tool, and six lists of tool versions in them. When user choose what versions of tools he want to download, client download all necesarry tools in chosen directory.

Of course, tools are often updated, so, I made six text files on server directory for every tool, written in this format:

```
1.5.3,1.5.2,1.5.1
```

What I want to do is to:

1. Read text file from the server (using WebClient for example), split
   this numbers and check if first version number of them is higher than first
   version number in combo box (drop down list in every combo box is in same
   format, starting from newer version to older).
2. If number **is** higher, download file to *Application Data* (I already have   variable for this
   that gives
   `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`)
   and update combo box drop down list.

I would be very appreciate for easiest way to do this :)